# Are identical primary keys bad practice?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a site where users can register and create a profile, therefore I am using two MySQL tables within a database e.g. `users` and `user_profile`.

The `users` table has an `auto increment primary key` called `user_id`.

The `user_profile` table has the same `primary key` called `user_id` however it is not `auto increment`.

**see note for why I have multiple tables.*

When a user signs up, data from the registration form is inserted into users, then the `last_insert_id()` is input into the `user_id` field of the `user_profile` table. I use transactions to ensure this always happens.

My question is, is this bad practice?

Should I have a `unique auto increment primary key` for the `user_profile` table, even though one user can only ever have one profile?

Maybe there are other downsides to creating a database like this?

I'd appreciate if anyone can explain why this is a problem or if it's fine, I'd like to make sure my database is as efficient as possible.

**Note:** I am using seperate tables for user and user_profile because user_profile contains fields that are potentially null and also will be requested much more than the user table, due to the data being displayed on a public profile.

Maybe this is also bad practice and they should be lumped in one table?

Comment: Not explicitly declaring primary keys is a very bad idea. It disables almost all optimizations MySQL has to speed things up. And it forces MySQL to create hidden primary key (that you cannot reach). Never do it.

Comment: FWIW, [you probably don't need transactions around `last_insert_id()`.](http://kera.name/articles/2011/08/one-less-bug-to-worry-about/)

Comment: @Johan: I am declaring user_id as the primary key in user_profile, it's just it wont be auto increment.

Comment: Oh, OK, in that cause you're cool. Note that MySQL will wrap a single SQL statement in it's own transaction, you only need to use transaction in a chain of 2 or more SQL-statements.

Comment: have you considered using a single table & a couple of views ? if your goal is efficiency this has to be the best solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find this a good approach, I'd give bonus point if you use a foreign key relation and preferably cascade when deleting the user from the user table.

As too separated the core user data in one table, and the option profile data in another - **good job**. Nothing more annoying then a 50 field dragonish entry with 90% empty values.

Comment: This is not as trivial as you state this. Having a foreign key relation implies having a innodb storage engine on mysql. Switching from myisam to innodb is not as trivial as the `ALTER` may seem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I had considered foreign keys but it looked like it might be easier for me to just ignore them. I will give them another look though!

Comment: @fyr: I use Innodb storage engine anyway, it's a requirement for the transactions.

Comment: @Alex: You don't need transactions for `last_insert_id()`.

Comment: @Tomalak: Ahh yes I know, but I just wanted to make sure that the user_profile was always created when a user tries to signup, to save any hassle should the server crash etc.

Comment: @alex: then i would totally agree with wesley to have foreign key relations with the delete cascade. As side note it is not totally clear in your post that you use innodb because of the note about transactions there are different concepts than using storage engine features.

Comment: @fyr: Ahh ok sorry, I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally frowned upon, but as long as you can provide the reasoning for the 1 to 1 relationship I'm sure it is fine.

I have used them when I have hundreds of columns (and it would be more logical to split them out into separate tables)
or I need a thinner table to speed up fullscans

In your case I would use a single table and create a couple of views.

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

In general a single table approach is more logical, quicker, simpiler, and uses less space.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was expecting it to be "frowned upon". I will have to research what views are, I admit my knowledge of MySQL is not yet where I would like it to be. Of course I don't know how big the user_profile table will be in the future, surely keeping it in a seperate table would avoid any future difficulties?

Comment: its stange being the only person who does not think it is a good idea........if you think about it it is far less efficient as the database has to check the foreign key (assuming you are using them) & maintain 2 index structures.

Comment: if you used views to hide the underlying physical structure you could change from a single table to a multi 1 to 1 structure without changing any code simply point the user_profile view to  the new table

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a promising technique I will use your link and look into it.

Comment: I decided to go ahead and buy MySQL by Paul DuBois and I just came across the section on views which let me consider your answer. It seems a view would make writing queries simpler, however any benefit from speed or space would be minimal and some would suggest that if tables were to become large (thousands of rows+) that a view could actually decrease performance. I may just stick with the 1-1 relationship.

Comment: well I have learnt something new there, looks like MYSQL is a little weak at optimising views (when compared to other databases), and can cause issues in some situations... http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-algorithms.html Although in your case, selecting single rows by the primary key, I would think it would make little difference.

Comment: Yes I found both of those posts while looking into them, it seems mainly to do with the creation of temporary tables, I believe the merge algorithm is fine. Thank you for suggesting it initially though, I ended up learning a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bad practice. Sometimes it's quite useful, especially if you want one class to deal with authentication, and not load all profile data. You can then modify how your authentication works, build web services and so on, with little care about maintaining data structures about profiles information which is likely to change as your project evolves.

Answer (score 0):

This is *very good practice*.

It's right at the core of writing good, modular, *normalised* relational database structures.